# How to add a dynamic cursor to a plsql function

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I want to add a dynamic cursor in to my plsql function. where_clause_ is my in parameter for the function. It could be vary. Below is my code.

```
FUNCTION Filter_Data_With_Security(
   where_clause_  IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   CURSOR check_sequrity IS 
      SELECT 1
      FROM tab b
      WHERE where_clause_
AND b.col1 = 'C2';    

BEGIN
   OPEN check_sequrity;
   FETCH check_sequrity INTO temp_;
   IF (check_sequrity%FOUND) THEN
      CLOSE year_exists;
      exist_ := 'TRUE';
   ELSE
      CLOSE check_sequrity;
      exist_ := 'FALSE';
   END IF;
   RETURN exist_;
END Filter_Data_With_Security;
```

But this gives me an error as follows

> ### PL/SQL: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator error at line no :9109

Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example 7.4 [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm)

```
FUNCTION Filter_Data_With_Security (where_clause_ IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   TYPE EmpCurTyp IS REF CURSOR;

   check_sequrity   EmpCurTyp;
   v_stmt_str       VARCHAR2 (200);
   temp_            NUMBER;
   exists_          VARCHAR2 (20);
BEGIN
   -- Dynamic SQL statement with placeholder:
   v_stmt_str := 'SELECT 1 FROM tab b WHERE ' || where_clause_ || 'AND b.col1 = ''C2''';

   OPEN check_sequrity FOR v_stmt_str;

   FETCH check_sequrity INTO temp_;

   IF (check_sequrity%FOUND) THEN
      CLOSE year_exists;

      exist_ := 'TRUE';
   ELSE
      CLOSE check_sequrity;

      exist_ := 'FALSE';
   END IF;

   RETURN exist_;
END Filter_Data_With_Security;
```

Dynamic SQL are not very secure ;). You should check for possible SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought. This option also you can try. Basically you need to check if any record returned from the basic input or not. I dont think we need to loop for that. Hope below snippet helps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Filter_Data_With_Security(
    where_clause_ IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  lv_num DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE;
  exist_ VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  lv_sql:='SELECT  1 FROM tab b WHERE '||where_clause_||' AND b.col1 = ''C2''';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_sql BULK COLLECT INTO lv_num;
  IF lv_num.EXISTS(1) THEN
    exist_ := 'TRUE';
  ELSE
    exist_ := 'FALSE';
  END IF;
  RETURN exist_;
END Filter_Data_With_Security;
```